# Apache redirect to separate api and doc directories

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Argh! Been pounding away at this but I just can't seem to get it working properly.

I have a dir structure like

```
/var/www/site
/var/www/site/ui
/var/www/site/api
/var/www/site/apidocs
```

I set the DocumentRoot to /var/www/site
and tried about 100 different things including Alias (they used to be in their own dirs) and Rewrites of course, but nothing I try seems to work well.
The API is using Phalcon and the UI and API have their own git repo's so I can just combine them, they need to stay separate.

Here's what I have which doesn't work...

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName dev.tld.com
    ServerAlias dev
    DocumentRoot /var/www/site
    AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
        RewriteRule ^/.* /var/www/site/ui/index.html
    <Directory /var/www/site/ui/>
    Options All
        AllowOverride All
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
    <DirectoryMatch .*\.git/.*>
    Deny From All
    </DirectoryMatch>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    LogLevel info
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    ServerSignature Off
    LogLevel alert rewrite:trace6
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName dev.tld.com
    ServerAlias dev
    ServerPath /api/
    RewriteEngine on
        RewriteRule ^(/api/.*) /var/www/site/api$1
    <Directory /var/www/site/api/>
    RewriteEngine on
        RewriteRule  ^$ public/    [L]
        RewriteRule  ((?s).*) public/$1 [L]
    Options All
        AllowOverride All
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
    <Directory "/var/www/site/api/public">
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^((?s).*)$ index.php?_url=/$1 [QSA,L]
        </Directory>
    <DirectoryMatch .*\.git/.*>
    Deny From All
    </DirectoryMatch>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    LogLevel info
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    ServerSignature Off
    LogLevel alert rewrite:trace6
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName dev.tld.com
    ServerAlias dev
    ServerPath /apidoc
    DocumentRoot /var/www/site/apidoc
    <Directory /var/www/site/apidoc/>
    Options All
        AllowOverride All
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
    <DirectoryMatch .*\.git/.*>
    Deny From All
    </DirectoryMatch>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    LogLevel info
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    ServerSignature Off
    LogLevel alert rewrite:trace6
</VirtualHost>
```

According to the [Phalcon](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/apache.html) docs, I need to do some redirecting for their api as well, which you see above for the /api directory

I haven't even tried to get the apidoc one working yet...

Edit:
I've managed to get a bit further by greatly simplifying it. The main UI loads, but the API returns a 500 error.

Here's what I have:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName lz4dev.tld.com
        ServerAlias dev
        DocumentRoot /var/www/site
        AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
        RewriteEngine On
        RedirectMatch ^/$ /ui/
        Alias /api /var/www/site/api
        Alias /apidoc /var/www/site/apidoc
        <Directory /var/www/site/ui/>
        Options All
        AllowOverride All
        Allow from all
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/site/api/>
        Options All
        AllowOverride All
        Allow from all
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/site/apidocs/>
        Options All
        AllowOverride All
        Allow from all
        </Directory>
        <DirectoryMatch .*\.git/.*>
        Deny From All
        </DirectoryMatch>
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        LogLevel info
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
        ServerSignature Off
        LogLevel alert rewrite:trace6
</VirtualHost>
```

Then in the api/.htaccess, I have:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule  ^$ public/    [L]
    RewriteRule  ((?s).*) public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

And in api/public/.htaccess, I have:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^((?s).*)$ index.php?_url=/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Here are the last few lines of the error log:

```
[Thu Sep 17 13:42:56.808052 2015] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 472] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 10.2.180.248:53810] 10.2.180.248 - - [dev.tld.com/sid#7fc91bf345c8][rid#7fc91bef7390/initial/redir#2] [perdir /var/www/site/api/public/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/site/api/public/index.php -> index.php, referer: http://dev.tld.com/ui/
[Thu Sep 17 13:42:56.808063 2015] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 472] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 10.2.180.248:53810] 10.2.180.248 - - [dev.tld.com/sid#7fc91bf345c8][rid#7fc91bef7390/initial/redir#2] [perdir /var/www/site/api/public/] applying pattern '^((?s).*)$' to uri 'index.php', referer: http://dev.tld.com/ui/
[Thu Sep 17 13:42:56.808075 2015] [rewrite:trace4] [pid 472] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 10.2.180.248:53810] 10.2.180.248 - - [dev.tld.com/sid#7fc91bf345c8][rid#7fc91bef7390/initial/redir#2] [perdir /var/www/site/api/public/] RewriteCond: input='/var/www/site/api/public/index.php' pattern='!-d' => matched, referer: http://dev.tld.com/ui/
[Thu Sep 17 13:42:56.808094 2015] [rewrite:trace4] [pid 472] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 10.2.180.248:53810] 10.2.180.248 - - [dev.tld.com/sid#7fc91bf345c8][rid#7fc91bef7390/initial/redir#2] [perdir /var/www/site/api/public/] RewriteCond: input='/var/www/site/api/public/index.php' pattern='!-f' => not-matched, referer: http://dev.tld.com/ui/
[Thu Sep 17 13:42:56.808102 2015] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 472] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 10.2.180.248:53810] 10.2.180.248 - - [dev.tld.com/sid#7fc91bf345c8][rid#7fc91bef7390/initial/redir#2] [perdir /var/www/site/api/public/] pass through /var/www/site/api/public/index.php, referer: http://dev.tld.com/ui/
```

Answer (score 0):

Success!

Here's what I ended up with:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName lz4dev.tld.com
        ServerAlias dev
        DocumentRoot /var/www/site
        AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
        RewriteEngine On
        RedirectMatch ^/$ /ui/
        Alias /api /var/www/site/api
        Alias /apidoc /var/www/site/apidoc
        <Directory /var/www/site/ui/>
        Options All
        AllowOverride All
        Allow from all
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/site/api/>
       Options All
        AllowOverride All
        Allow from all
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/site/apidocs/>
        Options All
        AllowOverride All
        Allow from all
        </Directory>
        <DirectoryMatch .*\.git/.*>
        Deny From All
        </DirectoryMatch>
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        LogLevel info
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
        ServerSignature Off
        LogLevel alert rewrite:trace6
</VirtualHost>
```

and in api/public/.htaccess, I had to add /api/ to the rule, like so:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^((?s).*)$ index.php?_url=/api/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```